# How to write to stdout after redirecting FD

Tags: python, stdout

Please take a look at this python code below.

```
so = open('/tmp/test.log', 'a+')
os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
```

After executing that piece of code I would like to still have possibility to print something on standard stdout.

---

I already tried:

```
print('Foo\n', file=sys.__stdout__)
```

As according to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) could be a way to go.

```
sys.__stdin__
sys.__stdout__
sys.__stderr__
```

> These objects contain the original values of stdin, stderr and stdout
> at the start of the program. They are used during finalization, and
> could be useful to print to the actual standard stream no matter if
> the sys.std* object has been redirected.

But it's not in that case. Its still logging to my **test.log** file.

Python version: **3.4.8**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The general (not-at-all-Python-specific) answer for this is to use `dup2()` to copy your original stdout FD somewhere else *before* overwriting it. You'd need to do the same thing in bash, f/e, running `exec 4>&1` to make FD 4 a copy of FD 1, to have the ability to restore FD 1 to its original value after a `exec >/tmp/test.log`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `sys.__stdout__` points to FD 1, but if you overwrite FD 1, the Python interpreter has a handle on a file descriptor that no longer points to original stdout -- you changed out the destination of that FD *below* the interpreter's layer, at the OS level. Your Python file objects point to OS-level file *descriptors*; those descriptors determine what OS-level file (socket, stream, whatever) a given object is *really* connected to... so when you switch out the FD, you change *all* Python objects attached to it.

Comment: (aside: `exec 4>&1` actually does two separate `fdup()`s in bash, the second one from the dynamically-allocated FD returned by `fdup()` to `4`; if you want to copy just once and store the dynamically-allocated number, you need bash 4.1 or newer to be able to run `exec {stdout_copy_fd}>&1`, to put the number of the dynamically-assigned descriptor in the variable named `stdout_copy_fd`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason `sys.__stdout__` did not work is because you replaced the original stdout's file descriptor with `os.dup2()`, so **any** Python file object that is based on it would print to the newly-opened file. The old stdout actually gets **closed** when you do `dup2`, so there is no restoring it.

If you want to have all Python code that uses `sys.stdout` to print to `/tmp/test.log`, open a new file and assign it to `sys.stdout`.

```
sys.stdout = open('/tmp/test.log', 'a+')
```

The original `sys.stdout` will remain available as `sys.__stdout__`.

f you want also to redirect any code that writes directly to sys.stdout.fileno(), including subprocesses that you start with `os.system()` or `subprocess.call()`, while keeping access to the original stdout, things get more complex: you would need to `dup()` stdout first and save that, then use your `dup2()` call to replace FD 1:

```
saved_stdout_fd = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
saved_stdout = os.fdopen(saved_stdout_fd,'w')
so = open('/tmp/test.log', 'a+')
os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
```

Now `sys.stdout` goes to your `/tmp/test.log` and `saved_stdout` will write to the original stdout.

Comment: Yes, I need to redirect subprocesses. Thats why I'm replacing file descriptor. 
So copying oryginal stdout will be actually the only way?
@Charles Duffy

Comment: @DawidFieluba, err, if you just want to change the stdout for a subprocess, pass the `stdout=` argument to `subprocess.Popen`; that'll change things around after the `fork()` spinning off the subprocess but before the `execve()` that actually invokes the other program, so the FDs on your main interpreter don't need to be modified -- even temporarily -- at all.